# Jenkins job always queued with agent node when even when controller node is idle

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

I have setup a Jenkins server on a machine (controller node) and have setup one agent node as well.
I have added same label 'test' on both controller node as well as agent node. The same label 'test' has also been added to 'Restrict where this project can be run' property of my jenkins project.
The issue is, when I trigger 2 or more builds of this project, all are getting queued to run with one of the nodes only. (even when the other node is idle)
My expectation is if first build is running on agent node, second should run on the controller node and vice-versa.
Anything I am missing here ?

NOTE - Tried configuring both the nodes with Usage property values 'Use this node as much as possible' as well as 'Only build jobs matching with label expression' but found the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved now.
The 'Execute concurrent builds if necessary' option was NOT checked in my project because of which the executor was waiting for one build to complete before starting other build.
After checking this option, when 2 builds are triggered, they run simultaneously on master as well as slave node.